# How long should TinyMPU6050.h calibration run for?

Tags: mpu6050

I just found a lightweight library for the MPU6050 gyro. Example below.
mpu.Calibrate() never seems to end. I'm keeping it very still. When I take this out, the rest of the code works fine.

https://github.com/gabriel-milan/TinyMPU6050/blob/master/examples/ArduinoIDE_All_Gets_Example/ArduinoIDE_All_Gets_Example.ino

Answer (score 1):

I feel so sorry about the previous releases of TinyMPU6050. I've just released v0.5.0 that shall soon be available at the Arduino Library Manager index.

The calibration method indeed was messy, so I decided to keep it simple. I also removed dependencies of String objects and Serial stuff and it seems to work pretty fine now.

If you keep having issues with that, please let me know!

The official link to release 0.5.0 follows:
https://github.com/gabriel-milan/TinyMPU6050/releases/tag/0.5.0